# PhantomJS: require Script and set variables beforehand

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS for page automation. For my script, I need to load another script which is also used on the actual client-side of my webpage. This script contains some parts where global variables - which are assumed to be set before the script is loaded - are used.

Now my problem is that I can't figure out how to set these variables before I `require` them within PhantomJS.

This (obviously) didn't do the trick:

```
variableX = 1024;
var moduleX = require('myScripts.js');
```

Now what's the proper and intended way ( if there is one) to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to load a script into PhantomJS if it's already used on the client-side?

Comment: I am trying to test my [Bootstrap Tour](http://bootstraptour.com/) tours. For that I need to get the steps - contained in the script - to test it against the client. Maybe it's not clear at the first sight, but it definitely makes sense (at least to me).

Comment: Still not clear. The script you mention - does it have to be run entirely client-side? Is it different from the PhantomJS script?

Comment: The script where my tour is defined, is included within the client-side. Now to test the client-side behavior I am using exactly the same script in PhantomJS, reading an array of so-called 'steps' and iterate over them to test each step. These steps contain `path` properties, which are set using global variables (in the client-side). My goal is to set these variables also within PhantomJS.

Comment: Well, if you prepare you script as a CommonJS module, you *can* require it in Phantomjs. See **Module system** section here: http://phantomjs.org/release-1.7.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prepare the testing script as a CommonJS module, you can require it and use its methods and variables in PhantomJS.

From the docs: http://phantomjs.org/release-1.7.html

> As an example, supposed there is a script `universe.js` which contains the following code:
>
> ```
> exports.answer = 42;
> exports.start = function () {
>     console.log('Starting the universe....');
> }
> ```
>
> This module can be used in another script like the following:
>
> ```
> var universe = require('./universe');
> universe.start();
> console.log('The answer is', universe.answer);
> ```

And if you want to assign global variables from such a module you can use the `global` object as in node.js:

```
exports.start = function () {
    global.success = true;
    console.log('Starting the universe....');
}
```

Comment: You led me to the solution with this, thank you. Since I wanted to have something like arguments to my export, I replaced the `module.exports` property with a function that takes the global variables as arguments.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now. You wanted to use `variableX` inside of a module!